# Sheet doesn't open when triggered in onAppear

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

I've encountered a strange bug when a `sheet` doesn't open if triggered in `onAppear`.

The following **does not** trigger the `sheet` in Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sheetActive = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetActive) {
                Text("Sheet")
            }
            .onAppear {
                sheetActive = true
            }
    }
}
```

The `sheet` only pops up after I interact with the screen in any way.

However, if I wrap `Text` in `NavigationView` / `List` etc. it **does** work.

Also, even attaching a simple modifier (like `onChange`) triggers the `sheet`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sheetActive = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetActive) {
                Text("Sheet")
            }
            .onAppear {
                sheetActive = true
            }
            .onChange(of: sheetActive) {
                print($0)
            }
    }
}
```

It also works when I trigger the `sheet` asynchronously:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sheetActive = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetActive) {
                Text("Sheet")
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    sheetActive = true
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in iOS 14.3 or some intended change I'm not aware of?

Comment: Have tried changing sequence of sheets and appear method and adding delay

Comment: Changing the order doesn't work either. And I don't even need a delay, it works with a simple `DispatchQueue.main.async` as well. Just the *standard* way doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your `sheetActive` to `true` it should open upon initialization.

The bugs of using `onAppear()` to initialize/active stuff are constantly being mentioned in SO and the Apple forums. It is very unreliable.

```
struct ActiveSheetView: View {
    @State private var sheetActive = true
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetActive) {
                Text("Sheet")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this looks like a bug then.